# Pandas Dataframe pivoting: making new columns from column values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

How can I convert [Original Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TgGs8.png) to the [Desired Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0FQ4Z.png)?

```
Original DataFrame
--------------------------------------------------
| Key | Value | Month              |
--------------------------------------------------
| 1       | 123 | 1
--------------------------------------------------
| 1       | 456| 2
--------------------------------------------------
| 1       | 789| 3
--------------------------------------------------
| 2       | 111| 1
--------------------------------------------------
| 2       | 222| 2
--------------------------------------------------
| 2       | 333| 3
--------------------------------------------------

Desired DataFrame
--------------------------------------------------
| Key | Month_1 | Month_2 | Month_3             |
--------------------------------------------------
|1  |123    |456    |789|
--------------------------------------------------
|2  |111    |222    |333|
--------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: **PLEASE DO NOT POST TEXT AS IMAGES**. Copy and paste the text into your question. Images are not searchable, and can not be interpreted by screen readers for those with visual impairments. Use the [edit] link to modify your question. See [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1426065) for more information.

Comment: Use `df.pivot(index="Key",columns="Month",values="Value")`.

Comment: @HenryYik Thanks it worked. But now how can I combine the column names into one Month_1 | Month_2 | Month_3  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use stack() and unstack() to transform it.

```
df = df.set_index(['Month','Key']).stack().unstack(level=0).reset_index()
df = df.drop('level_1', axis=1)
df.columns = ['Key','Month_1','Month_2','Month_3']

df
    Key Month_1 Month_2 Month_3
0   1   123     456     789
1   2   111     222     333
```